# Karma tests on Edge and azure pipelines

Tags: karma-runner, azure-pipelines, microsoft-edge, karma-mocha

When trying to run my karma test suit on Edge, in Azure pipelines, I have the following error:

```
18 05 2020 16:34:20.217:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v5.0.7 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
18 05 2020 16:34:20.217:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Edge with concurrency unlimited
18 05 2020 16:34:20.312:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Edge
18 05 2020 16:34:46.536:ERROR [launcher]: Killing Edge process failed. Error: Command failed: taskkill /t /f /im MicrosoftEdge.exe
ERROR: The process "MicrosoftEdge.exe" not found.

18 05 2020 16:34:46.536:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Edge
    undefined
18 05 2020 16:34:46.536:ERROR [launcher]: Edge stdout: 
Couldn't find Edge URL with URL: 00D53958
Found
18 05 2020 16:34:46.536:ERROR [launcher]: Edge stderr: 
18 05 2020 16:34:46.536:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Edge again (1/2).
18 05 2020 16:35:07.958:ERROR [launcher]: Killing Edge process failed. Error: Command failed: taskkill /t /f /im MicrosoftEdge.exe
ERROR: The process "MicrosoftEdge.exe" not found.

18 05 2020 16:35:07.958:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Edge
    undefined
18 05 2020 16:35:07.958:ERROR [launcher]: Edge stdout: 
Couldn't find Edge URL with URL: 00100250
Found
18 05 2020 16:35:07.958:ERROR [launcher]: Edge stderr: 
18 05 2020 16:35:07.973:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Edge again (2/2).
18 05 2020 16:35:29.343:ERROR [launcher]: Killing Edge process failed. Error: Command failed: taskkill /t /f /im MicrosoftEdge.exe
ERROR: The process "MicrosoftEdge.exe" not found.

18 05 2020 16:35:29.343:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Edge
    undefined
18 05 2020 16:35:29.343:ERROR [launcher]: Edge stdout: 
Couldn't find Edge URL with URL: 013BFFB0
Found
18 05 2020 16:35:29.343:ERROR [launcher]: Edge stderr: 
18 05 2020 16:35:29.359:ERROR [launcher]: Edge failed 2 times (cannot start). Giving up.
```

It is running in a microsoft hosted windows-2019 VM, according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/ui-testing-considerations?view=azure-devops&tabs=mstest#visible-ui-testing-using-microsoft-hosted-agents), it should be configured correctly.
Has anyone ever made this setup work?

For the record, Internet Explorer works fine the same setup!

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1038365/launch-edge.html on microsoft's side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make that work with a custom plugin: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-edge-launcher

You can then use the `Edge` browser.

Comment: This launcher didnt work for me, i used: https://github.com/koddsson/karma-edgium-launcher

Comment: I used this one with Chromium Edge: https://github.com/ChiragRupani/karma-chromiumedge-launcher

Answer (score 2):

A simple workaround if integrating with edge fails: even if you do not have Chrome installed, you can set the default browser to ChromeHeadless in the the `karma.conf.js` by changing the 'browsers' setting to 'ChromeHeadless' as follows:

```
browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
```

then once you are running the tests you can open `http://localhost:9876/` in Microsoft Edge  and it will show the regular karma testing window.

Alternatively, without setting the default browser, you can also do the same by using the command `ng test --browsers ChromeHeadless`

Comment: I am doing test automation. What you are describing can be done easily with the `karma start --no-browser` option